# вывести второе значение из массива

Tags: php

Подскажите, есть такой массив:

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-06-01" [1]=> array(1) { ["text"]=> string(7) "Test 1 " } [2]=> string(10) "2017-06-15" [3]=> array(1) { ["text"]=> string(7) "Test 2 " } [4]=> string(10) "2017-06-14" [5]=> array(1) { ["text"]=> string(6) "Test 3" } [6]=> string(10) "2017-06-07" [7]=> array(1) { ["text"]=> string(6) "Test 3" } [8]=> string(10) "2017-06-12" [9]=> array(1) { ["text"]=> string(6) "Test 4" } }
```

Как вывести не дату, а второе значение text?

Comment: С каждого ?  Или конкретного ?

Comment: @Sergey как то не пойму суть вопроса? если просто не знаете как обращаться к полям массива то смотрите здесь. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто нужен массив можно так:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        echo $value['text'];
    }
}
```

Еще лучше проерять существует ли такое поле

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value['text'])) {
        echo $value['text'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А если дело касается wordpress и работа с массивом field

```
$images=get_field('images')); 
foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
if (isset($key['url'])) {
  echo var_export($value);
}
```

В images выводится массив